# Java blocking queue download process scenario

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following scenario .

I have incoming file download requests and each download is happening in different thread until pool size is exceeded. And after  a download completed, a processor processes the downloaded item. So I created the following. I wonder if uses of thread and executors make sense

DownloadTaskProcessor

```
public class DownloadTaskEnqueuer {
    private static final BlockingQueue<Task> downloadQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    private static final BlockingQueue<Task> processQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    private static final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    public void offer(Task task) {
        return downloadQueue.offer(task);
    }

    public void createPool(int size) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            executor.execute(new DownloadTask(downloadQueue, processQueue);
            executor.execute(new ProcessTask(processQueue));
        }
    }
}
```

Download task

```
public class DownloadTask implements Runnable {
    private BlockingQueue<Task> downloadQueue;
    private BlockingQueue<Task> processQueue;
    
    // constructor for initing two queue

    public void offer(Task task) {
        return processQueue.offer(task);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
           Task task = downloadQueue.poll();
           if (task != null) {
               task.getDownloadTask().download();
               offer(task);    
           } else {
               // sleep 250 ms 
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Process task

```
public class ProcessTask implements Runnable {
    private BlockingQueue<Task> processQueue;
    
    // constructor for initing queue
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
           Task task = processQueue.poll();
           if (task != null) {
                task.getProcessTask().process();
           } else {
               // sleep 250 ms 
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Use case (pseudo)

```
createPool(10);

listener.listen((task) -> {
    downloadTaskEnqueuer.offer(task);
}
```

Comment: I'm missing the `Task` implementation, otherwise looks quite good to me without testing it. Check whether `poll` can actually return `null`.

Answer (score 1):

In your `DownloadTaskEnqueuer` it might be a little bit weird to mix instance methods with `static` fields (unless there is more code which you omitted). It might be better to either use instance fields (i.e. remove `static` from `downloadQueue`, `processQueue` and `executor`) or make the methods `static`.

You `DownloadTaskEnqueuer.offer(...)` method has `void` as return type but contains a `return` statement returning a value.

`Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` is not that well suited for your use case. You are creating a fixed number of work tasks which run indefinitely so an executor which creates a new thread per task would work equally well. Normally you also don't submit an indefinitely running work task which itself performs tasks to an executor, but instead directly submit the tasks to the executor.

This leads to the next question: How are you shutting down workers? It appears with your current code the `DownloadTask` and `ProcessTask` run forever. Or is there no need to shut down workers in your use case?

Using `BlockingQueue.poll()` and then waiting seems a little bit inefficient. Since you are already dealing with BlockingQueue you could use the blocking method [`BlockingQueue.take()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#take()).

If I may make a suggestion, it appears [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) would be well suited for your use case:

```java
public class DownloadProcessor {
    private final ExecutorService downloadExecutor;
    private final ExecutorService processingExecutor;

    public DownloadProcessor(int poolsSize) {
        downloadExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool​(poolsSize);​
        processingExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool​(poolsSize);​
    }

    public CompletableFuture<Void> downloadAndProcess(DownloadTask task) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> task.download(), downloadExecutor)
            // Assumes that DownloadTask.download() returns ProcessingTask which
            // has method `process()`
            .thenAcceptAsync​(task -> task.process(), processingExecutor);
    }
    
    public void shutdown() {
        downloadExecutor.shutdown();
        processExecutor.shutdown();
        // Maybe also call awaitTermination​
    }
}
```